# Error Code : 1064 on MySQL update query

Tags: mysql, database, updates

```
Table: immunization                 
id  vac_id  vaccine_id
1   5       0
2   5       0
3   3       0
4   4       0
5   4       0

Table: vaccine
id  vac_id
8   1
9   2
10  3
11  4
12  5
```

I have two table , now I want to set id of vaccine table into vaccine_id of immunization table by matching vaccine.vac_id = immunization.vac_id

TO do It i have used the query like but getting error 1064

```
UPDATE immunization
SET  immunization.vaccine_id = vaccine.id
FROM vaccine,immunization
WHERE  vaccine.vac_id = immunization.vac_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE immunization i
join vaccine v
on i.vac_id=v.vac_id
SET  i.vaccine_id = v.id
```

set comes last

Comment: yw, now onward and cure us with those vaccines